# LayoutInflater Attributes

Tags: android

I see in the `LayoutInflater` code where the actual view class is [instantiated via reflection](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/view/LayoutInflater.java#544) (`LayoutInflater` - `createView()` method), however, I fail to see where the actual attributes are set on that view.

Can someone point me to the location where the `AttributeSet` is actually applied to the instantaited view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Line 584 in the referred to code:

```
Object[] args = mConstructorArgs;
args[1] = attrs;
return constructor.newInstance(args);
```

Comment: Haha, didn't look close enough.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's at the bottom..., check:

```
Object[] args = mConstructorArgs;
args[1] = attrs;
return constructor.newInstance(args);
```